# Is this defined behaviour?

Tags: c++

I need to add the members of lots of classes with a large number of members. Would this method of summing members of two objects holding statistics be defined behaviour? Is there a safer low-verbose method of doing the same thing?

```cpp
    template<typename Class, typename T>
    void add_typed_range(Class& l, const Class& r, T Class::* from, T Class::* to)
    {
        auto* it_l = &(l.*from);
        const auto* to_it_l = &(l.*to);
        auto* it_r = &(r.*from);
        const auto* to_it_r = &(r.*to);
        for (; it_l <= to_it_l; ++it_l, ++it_r)
        {
            *it_l += *it_r;
        }
    }
    
    struct A
    {
        double a, b, c, d, e, f, g;
        int l, m, n, o, p;
    
        A& operator+=(const A& r)
        {
            add_typed_range(*this, r, &A::a, &A::g);
            add_typed_range(*this, r, &A::l, &A::p);
            return *this;
        }
    };

    void example()
    {
        A a, b;
        a += b;
    }
```

I would like to keep the parameters named. As the names contains a lot of information and are much easier work with. Changing to an `array` per value-type with an `enum` index is a way to keep the information but causes a lot of changes to existing code, just to allow "addition" of the type to itself to be easier.

It strange to me `auto& operator+=(const Object&) = default` is not auto generatable by the compiler.

Comment: why are the members not part of a `vector` or `array` ?

Comment: No, this is undefined behavior, you are not allowed to treat individual variables as if they were part of the same array

Comment: fwiw, this looks like an attempt to save keystrokes. If your class has *too many* members, then your issue is the design rather than keystrokes

Comment: You can do it kind of the other way around, make an array and you can access the values   by name using structured bindings (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding). 
`std::array<int, 7> values{};      auto& [a, b, c, d, e, f, g] = object.values;`
Or you can give your struct named getters. But indeed what problem are you trying to really solve?

Comment: This is [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Please describe what this code should do, not how you trying it force it to do something. For me it looks like you should just use an array which can be indexed.

Comment: `auto& operator+=(const Object&) = default;`
Is what i'd really like, but there's probably some good reasons it hasn't been added.

Comment: Your code is assuming that all of the members between (the passed) `from` and `to` are the same type, and contained in the same object.    If that assumption is not valid, the behaviour will be undefined.   If the assumption is valid, why haven't you stored the values in a container (e.g. `std::vector` if size is not known at compile time, `std::array` if size is fixed at compile time)?   Doing it with standard containers, you can add things up using standard algorithms (e.g. `std::accumulate()`) or a simple loop.

Answer (score 6):

No. Your code has undefined behavior.

Your code makes certain assumptions. Some hold, but not all. Members of same access level are layedout in memory in the order of declaration. Thats fine. Though pointer arithmetics is only allowed for pointers to elements of the same array. I think you can always get a pointer one past an object (its like an array with a single element), but thats it. Using pointer arithmetics to go beyond that is undefined.

The simpler, less verbose and legal way to do what you want is to use `std::vector` or `std::array` for the members:

```
struct A {
    std::array<double,7> abcdefg;
    std::array<int,5> lmnop;
};
```

Adding two arrays is a simple loop. No need to use fancy pointer arithmetics or the like.

Comment: In modern C++ (C++20?) the access level will be ignored in the layout. So memory order is always as written regardless of public/protected/private.